# Disk Usage Analyzer and other programs reporting incorrect partition capacities

Tags: 13.04, partitioning, disk, gparted, disk-usage

I recently resized/moved my home partition and then expanded my root partition into the free space remaining. I did this all off a bootable usb with gparted. When i started ubuntu back up and ran osm2pgsql(it converts map files into databse form) it complained about not having enough space in the root directory. Running all the usual df -h, gparted, gnome-disk, gnome-system-monitor and checking properties of my root directory showed that it has a capacity of 66.2GB, of which 6.0GB is used. When I use Disk Usage Analyzer though, it reports a size of ~6GB(which i guess is what osm2pgsql detects too). The strange thing is that I didn't even start with 6GB before i resized/moved. I started with about 12GB if my memory serves correctly. Also, my home partition is reported to have shrunk to 64.1GB from about 1.4TB before when using Disk Usage Analyzer. As a final clue, disk Usage Analyzer reports the correct size of root before it scans the folders - not sure if that helps.

[image: disk usage analyzer after scan]

[image: terminal]

Answer (score 1):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1122670

This is a very large topic, so go to section #5, where it says:

> While DUA provides valuable information, it often brings up questions
> about its use. Here are some things to keep in mind:
>
> Once a scan is
> complete, the top entry, whether it is the system or a single folder,
> will always show 100%. The sub-folder percentages add up to 100%. 100%
> does not necessarily mean there is no space left on the partition.

A similar thing happened to me on Debian 7/Gnome 3.  I tried to install google-chrome, but it installs to /opt so my root partition filled and it aborted.  Gnome opens Disk Usage Analyzer and it says 100%, but df only says 52% in use.  So in my case, DUA misled me and wasted my time only.  I'm sorry I can't say why your program fails through, I would only say make sure that it is not generating large files somewhere on that partition.